# Laravel - Get data last 24 hours, 1 week or 1 month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying to grab only data which are in last 24 hours, 1 week, 1 month. I have working code, but if I get it correctly it's "other way". By that I mean, If date is at the moment 30-Nov-2016 and I set the Data value to 1-Dec-2016, then the 24 Hour one still grabs the information, but it shouldn't. If date is 30-Nov-2016 and I set it to 28-Nov-2016, then the 24 Hour one doesn't grab it. For me It sounds like it's backwards. I hope the explanation is understandable.

```
$getItemsOneDay = Deposit::where('steam_user_id',0)->where('status', Deposit::STATUS_ACTIVE)->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1440))->get();
$getItemsOneWeek = Deposit::where('steam_user_id',0)->where('status', Deposit::STATUS_ACTIVE)->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10080))->get();
$getItemsOneMonth = Deposit::where('steam_user_id',0)->where('status', Deposit::STATUS_ACTIVE)->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(43200))->get();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You wrote `created_at > time`.

So you ask laravel to search all data greater than now(). So you look into the future.

Either you want to...

- look at points before a certain point in time: `created_at < time`
- look at points after a certain point in time: `created_at > time`
- look at points within an interval of passed time: `created_at > start && created_at < end`

If i got you right you are searching for the third option. So you need to do something like `...->where("created_at",">",Carbon::now()->subDay())->where("created_at","<",Carbon::now())->...`

Hopefully, I got you right here.

Comment: In laravel 5.6 you can send multiple array of conditions to where() and it does **and** between them. Also now is a method not a constant.

Answer (score 3):

`->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateTimeString())->get();`

to get the data created within last 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

```
  /**  Check the below function; it is working fine.
    Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateTimeString() this line give us result of last 24 hour. 
    1)carbon::now mean current date time.
    2)subDay() function subtract day
    3)toDateTimeString function give us datetime  
            $now = Carbon::now(); //get current datetime
            $start = $now->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'); //get start of week and it is started form Monday
            $end = $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'); this function get end of week and it is ended Sunday means current week always ended on Sunday.
     similarly we can use carbon::now()->month for a month, carbon::now()->week for a week
    for current month start carbon::now()->startOfMonth() it give us result start of month datetime and 
    for current month end carbon::now()->endOfMonth() it give us result end of month datetime.
    for carbon::now()->startOfYear() it give us current start year.
    for carbon::now()->endOfYear() it give us current end datetime
     get data after comparing with created that is stored datetime in database.
  **/  
    
        
               public function getanswer_24hours(Request $request)
                  {
                      $ans = Answer::where('user_id',$request->user_id)->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateTimeString())->get();
                      
                      if(count($ans) > 0)
                    {
                       
                        $result = 'yes';
                        return response()->json(['data' =>['answer' => $ans,'result' => $result, 'message' => 'get Answer Before 24hours SuccessFully!!','status' => true],200,'ok']);
                        
                    }else{
                       
                        $result = 'no';
                        return response()->json(['data' =>['answer' => [], 'result' => $result, 'message' => 'get Answer Failed!!'],404,'no']);
                    }
            
                      
                  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).